# How to effectively modify a library to be able to function with Mozzi Library?

Tags: arduino-uno, library, audio

I have sketch that runs almost exactly as I would want it to. Now I am trying to add sound to it using the Mozzi Library instead of just using the tone function. This way I can avoid having to put a memory card slot and a memory card with the Arduino, considering Mozzi produces some good sound. The problem is that Mozzi takes over the timers and a lot of other things. The analogread and the delaymicroseconds have been replaced by Mozzi functions mozzi analog read and mozziMicros etc. I rewrote my sketch adding mozzi relted stuff, but it stops functioning like it should, but it does compile. SO I am assuming I would need to change the Library to replace original functions with mozzi functions like mozzianalogread. On doing this, several errors about arguments and declaration for these functions pop up. Is editing the other library a necessary step? If yes, then what should be things to look out for to prevent such errors.

Comment: Without knowing what Mozzi is (an Australian mosquito?), I'd say that your problem is that you need to include the Mozzi library in this "other" library so it knows what these mozzi* functions are.

Comment: http://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/examples/#08.Samples
I did do that and added all the commands and the header to the QTouchADC library.